# Properties of decreasing sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove a property of Lebesgue measure sets that says:

If the $A_{k}$'s are measurable and $A_{1} \supset A_{2} \supset A_{3} \supset \ldots,$ and if $\lambda (A_{1}) < \infty, $ then  $$\lambda ( \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}  A_{k} ) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda (A_{k}).$$

And I'm trying to emulate the proof of the previous property that says:

If the $A_{k}$'s are measurable and $A_{1} \subset A_{2} \subset A_{3} \subset \ldots,$ then  $$\lambda ( \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}  A_{k} ) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda (A_{k}).$$

And they express the union $\bigcup A_{k}$ as a disjoint union like this:
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k} = A_{1} \cup \bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty} (A_{k} \sim A_{k-1})$$
So I'm trying to create a increasing sequence from my decreasing one like this:

Say $(A_{k})= A_{1} \supset A_{2} \supset \ldots$ then $B_{k}=A_{1} - A_{k}$ and I'm not quite sure if $(B_{k})$ is an increasing sequence, and if so, I'm able to express this as a disjoint union like before?

I don't know if I'm on good track or I'm completely lost, can you help me with this please?

Also, what's the point of  $\lambda (A_{1}) < \infty $ how can I use that?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track! Let's keep going from where you are:

We define $B_k := A_1 - A_k$. Then, as you can very easily prove, this is an increasing sequence of sets. It is now important to notice that $$\bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty}B_k = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty}(A_1 - A_k) = A_1 - \bigcap_{k = 1}^{\infty}A_k.$$ The only reason we are doing this is that we are now in the position to apply the previous result, which gives $$\lambda\Big(\bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty}B_k\Big) = \lim_{k \to \infty}{\lambda(B_k)}.$$

*Please notice that you can directly apply the result without proving it again, hence there is no need to make these sets into disjoint sets.*

Let's write explicitly what those quantities are: $$\text{LHS} = \lambda\Big(\bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty}B_k\Big) = \lambda\Big(A_1 - \bigcap_{k = 1}^{\infty}A_k\Big) = \lambda(A_1) - \lambda\Big(\bigcap_{k = 1}^{\infty}A_k\Big),$$ $$\text{RHS} = \lim_{k \to \infty}{\lambda(B_k)} = \lim_{k \to \infty}\lambda(A_1 - A_k) = \lambda(A_1) - \lim_{k \to \infty}\lambda(A_k).$$

Hence, $$\lambda(A_1) - \lambda\Big(\bigcap_{k = 1}^{\infty}A_k\Big) = \lambda(A_1) - \lim_{k \to \infty}\lambda(A_k),$$
which simplifies yielding the desired equality. It is a good exercise to convince yourself that you cannot conclude unless $\lambda(A_1) < \infty.$

($\infty - 1 = \infty = \infty - 2$, but $1$ and $2$ are different, so you can't cross out a quantity unless it is finite.)

---

It is worth mentioning that there is nothing special about $A_1$: the result continues to hold even if $\lambda(A_i) = \infty$ for $i = 1,\dots, N-1$ and $\lambda(A_{N}) < \infty.$ To prove this drop the first $N-1$ terms (they are irrelevant when computing the intersection) and replace $A_1$ with $A_N$ in the proof above.

---

There is a very easy example that shows the importance of the finiteness assumption: let $A_k = (k,\infty).$ Then $\lambda(A_k) = \infty$ for every $k$, but $\cap_k A_k = \emptyset$, so that $$0 = \lambda\Big(\bigcap_{k = 1}^{\infty}A_k\Big) \neq \lim_{k \to \infty}\lambda(A_k) = \infty.$$

Comment: That's great! Thak you soo much! I was actually crying about expressing $ \bigcup B_{k} $ as a disjoint union. And I'm already convinced that my $ (B_{k}) $ is an increasing sequence. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could help! Also, I have edited the question several times trying to clean it from typos and I have tried to expand a little on the importance of the finiteness assumption. Make sure you check out this updated version :)

Comment: Actually, I was about to ask you for an example and you already did! That was really helpful, you help me understood that perfectly.